# deleting records on Prod through Admin GUI vs CLI vs Code

Tags: database, design-patterns

This will probably be subjective, but just wondering what the desired way of deleting records on a production DB would be (assuming you do not want to soft-delete archive and actually purge it)

I'm just trying to delete a couple of records (as opposed to a bulk cleanup). In this case, I don't see anything wrong with using some kind of Admin GUI tool and removing the items this way.

A similar option is to go into the CLI for the DB and do it there too. In my opinion, the caveat here is that you can accidentally delete all records by forgetting to include a where clause. Doing so in a GUI would prevent this.

Another option is to write some script and do it that way too. But, since this is automated, you may realize there's a problem after it's too late.

No matter what, I understand the need to backup often and prior to doing anything on Prod DB too.

Any insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents: When making any updates to prod, a general rule of thumb that should be followed is: *Whatever can be done, can be undone*. That being said as part of GDPR compliance, the personal data will have to be deleted permanently.

Though this would depend on factors like the volume of events to be deleted/performance expectations, the table should have a backup from where data could be restored if needed. If backup update is too costly, you can have soft delete such that a soft deleted rows gets removed permanently after "n" days.

**Code:** I believe the deletion logic should reside and be tested here. It needs to be exposed as an interface with safety checks rather than just giving the ability to run any query to the users. This is also easy to test, maintain and extend.

**CLI:** Writing delete queries on SQL clients is not acceptable in my view. This is prone to error. Ideally the SQL client user should not even have access to delete data or tables.

**GUI:**. Honestly, I would not put GUI in-front of my code. Deletion of prod data should be as difficult and restrictive as possible. Only reason I could see for implementing GUI is if this is a frequent operation, then a user friendly GUI can be used easily by support/admin teams.